# Possible error in Lipschutz

Tags: general-topology

The problem asks to show that $f:(0,\infty)\to [-1,1]$ given by $f(x)=\sin (\frac {1}{x})$ is neither [open nor closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps). Where $(0,\infty)$ and $[-1,1]$ are subspaces of $\Bbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

While it is clear this is true if $[-1,1]$ is replaced with $\Bbb R$ , the images of open set will look like $[-1,a)$ , $(a,1]$ , or $[-1,-1]$ all of which are open in $[-1,1]$.

However the map is not closed since the image of $[\frac 1 {2\pi} , \infty)$ is $(0,1]$ which is not closed in $[-1,1]$.

So why is this map not open?

Comment: Because the author thought of "open in $\mathbb{R}$", I think. It is indeed open as a map with codomain $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer It's weird though, that he mentions that $[-1,1]$ are given the subspace topology. What is making me doubt it being wrong is the fact that the map is not closed in $[-1,1]$

Comment: It is wrong. The map is open. Since $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is a homeomorphism of $(0,\infty)$ to itself, you can as well look at $g(x) = \sin x$. $f$ is open if and only if $g$ is open. It's not hard to see that $\sin (I)$ is open in $[-1,1]$ for all open intervals $I \subset (0,\infty)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer This pretty much answers my question :) could you post this as an answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed an error. Probably the author thought of "open in $\mathbb{R}$", even though explicitly mentioning the subspace topology of $[-1,1]$.

Since $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is a homeomorphism $(0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$, $f$ is open [or closed] if and only if $g(x) = \sin x$ is open [resp. closed] as a map $(0,\infty) \to [-1,1]$.

It is relatively easy to show that $\sin (I)$ is open in $[-1,1]$ for every open interval $I \subset (0,\infty)$. For points with $-1 < \sin x < 1$, the function is a homeomorphism on a small enough neighbourhood of $x$ [so small that it contains no point with $\lvert \sin x\rvert = 1$], and if $\sin x = \pm 1$, for $0 < \varepsilon < \pi$, we have $\sin (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon) = (\cos \varepsilon, 1]$ resp. $\sin (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon) = [-1,-\cos \varepsilon)$, which are open in $[-1,1]$.